# Passing array as pointer to function and using sizeof() operator

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sizeof

I tried to get how many bytes are allocated for an array using standalone function but I failed. My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void testing(char *source);

int main(){

    char a[12] = "Hello World!";
    //printf("%d",sizeof(a));   Prints 12. I want to get this value
    testing(a); // Prints 4. I need to get 12 by using functions


return 0;
}

void testing(char *source){
    printf("%d",sizeof(source));
}
```

> I want to get result as 12 but output tells me that it is 4.

Comment: You can't get the size of an array from `sizeof` with a pointer.

Comment: It is like saying "I want 2+2 to be 5". You can keep to "want" it, but it won't happen. `sizeof` does not do this.

Comment: change function to `void testing( char (*source)[12] )` and then in function use `sizeof *source`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get result as 12 but output tells me that it is 4.

You can't get the size of an array when it's passed as pointer to function.

In `void testing(char *source)`, `source` is pointer, so `sizeof( pointer )` gives you 4 (4 bytes in your machine).

There is no way to find out the array size inside the function, as array parameter will decay to pointer anyway.

Comment: Thank u! is there an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: Nothing apart of passing the size explicitly one way or another.